# Analyze raw assembly using IDA Pro

Tags: ida, assembly

I have a raw assembly dump i.e.

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.bits 32
.global main    

main:
    push   ebp
...
```

And I know it's Intel x86 and the original function was most likely written in C. Now the question is whether I could use IDA to reverse this and get the original function?

Comment: IDA disassembles binaries. (It's what "IDA" stands for.) What you *have* here is disassembled code, as plain text. What do you hope IDA will do with it?

Comment: Ideally spit out some nice pseudocode?

Comment: From a text file? No. It needs a binary.

Comment: If you assemble the file you can load it in ida

Comment: @mrexodia that could work. can I just use gcc?

Comment: It looks like it’s masm/nasm/yasm syntax from the first line. Maybe try those, but yeah... Assemble into an object and then link into an executable should work.

Comment: Wait, I think you misunderstand something here, @S.L. IDA is a *dis*assembler. It will do the opposite of an assembler. Now _with_ the Hex-Rays plugin you will also get a decompiler, so in theory you will be able to get back some Pseudo-C code if all works out. But it may be a bit of a steep price tag (IDA+Hex-Rays) when a book on assembly will help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDA does not accept assembly input, so you need to convert it to some binary format first. This is generally done with an *assembler*, such as GNU Assembler or `gas` (part of GNU Binutils and usually installed with `gcc`), or different alternative assemblers such as `nasm`, `yasm`, `fasm` and so on. If you need help assembling a specific file, you can ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), providing as much info as possible.

Comment: This worked like a charm: I compiled the original snippet and got into a good old executable and then was able to analyze that with IDA and dump some useable pseudocode. Not exactly reverse engineer of the year over here but it works!